# Display one error message for 3 textboxes with mvc 4 razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm Currently validating a fax number in which I need to to only display one error message for all of 3 of the textboxes.  Like a Summary

It seems a bit picky/silly of a business requirement as there are 3 textboxes and all are required by themselves but if someone has done this before that would be nice.

In my Model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fax is Required...")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{3}$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid fax #")]
    public string poc_fax_1 { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fax is Required...")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{3}$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid fax #")]
    public string poc_fax_2 { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fax is Required...")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid fax #")]
    public string poc_fax_3 { get; set; }
```

View:

```
(@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.poc_fax_1, new { @class = "input-mini", @maxlength=3 })) -
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.poc_fax_1)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.poc_fax_2, new { @class = "input-mini", @maxlength=3 }) -
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.poc_fax_2)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.poc_fax_3, new { @class = "input-mini", @maxlength=4 })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.poc_fax_3)
```

[image]

Note:  Image is BEFORE I fixed the numeric entry only and thus updated the question.

Comment: Better you make use of validation summary, if you want error messages at one place.Still showing one message for different input controls doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, while I agree as a developer, I added an image of what happens and thus I can see why the stakeholder are wanting just 1 message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using annotations for each piece of the fax number you can check in the controller action if the 3 fields together are valid

Something like this: check in your controller

```
if (faxfield1 != null && faxfield2 != null && faxfield3 != null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("FaxError", "Fax is not valid");
}
```

Then use this in your view (once)

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("FaxError")
```

Note: this is just showing how you can do it in a other way, you'll have to use other validation ofc :)